# Dropping heavy file and File drop trigger using automation Studio

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio

My question will, let's assume I have 20 GB file to be dropped in SFTP which usually takes 5 min to upload, Since we are using File drop/  trigger which listen to the file being dropped, how does SFMC handle that? Is it going to wait until the file fully uploaded (Buffer time)? Or it is going to pick up the file as soon as it is dropped? which in our case not good practice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

File Drop Triggered Automations only trigger once the full file has uploaded to FTP.

So to answer your question, the automation will pick up the file after the 20gb file has finished uploading to SFTP, I have tested this in the past and it will wait until the full file has processed.